# Implement the Recipes class, which handle food recipes (name, description). The class should have an add (add a new recipe),

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I'm kinda confused , about if im storing the Name of the Recipe "TükőrTojás" and the desc of it , because even though, I pass the first test in the add test section, when it comes to , the delete  section, the , i fail the first test, my array size changes to 2, I guess its because the name there is already defined ?
Do i have to, somehow, store the already defined name into my Array list?
If i, have to do that , how should i?

```
public class Recipes {
/*
Implement the Recipes class, which handle food recipes (name, description).
The class should have an add (add a new recipe),
 */
    ArrayList<String> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
    public void add(String name, String desc)
    {   Collections.addAll(recipes,name,desc);
        System.out.println(recipes.get(0));
        System.out.println(recipes.get(1));
    }
    public void delete(String name)

    {  
        recipes.remove(name);
    }
}
```

````
@Test
    public void testDelete() {
        Recipes recipes = new Recipes();

        String name = "Tükörtojás";

        recipes.add(name, "1. Az olajat egy serpenyőben kellőképp felforrósítjuk és óvatosan beleütjük" +
                " a tojásokat.\r\n2. Keverés nélkül készre sütjük, míg a tojásfehérje megsül, de a sárgája" +
                " folyós marad.\r\n3. Hogy jobban átsüljön, a tojásfehérjét egy villa segítségével óvatosan" +
                " megmozgathatjuk.");

        assertEquals(1, recipes.recipes.size()); // The test i fail

        recipes.delete(name);

        assertEquals(0, recipes.recipes.size());
    }
    ```
````

Comment: I think you're probably supposed to write two classes - one which stores a single `Recipe`, and one which stores the collection of `Recipe` objects.  The latter will be the one that has an `add` method.

Comment: Try `ArrayList<Recipe>` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a JavaBean for Recipe to use it with your ArrayList, so instead of `ArrayList<String>` you would probably have `ArrayList<Recipe>`.

## RecipeBean.java

For this example I will create a JavaBean named `RecipeBean` which will contain the `Strings` `recipeName` and `recipeDescription`

```
public class RecipeBean {

    private String recipeName = "", recipeDescription = "";

    public RecipeBean() {
    }

    public String getRecipeName() {
        return recipeName;
    }

    public void setRecipeName(String recipeName) {
        this.recipeName = recipeName;
    }

    public String getRecipeDescription() {
        return recipeDescription;
    }

    public void setRecipeDescription(String recipeDescription) {
        this.recipeDescription = recipeDescription;
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.recipeName = "";
        this.recipeDescription = "";
    }
}
```

The class above will act as the `Recipe` object or item for a single Recipe.

## Recipe.java

Then in your class called `Recipe.class` I will declare the `ArrayList` now with the `RecipeBean` instead of `String` for more control.

```
ArrayList<RecipeBean> recipes = new ArrayList();


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Recipe {

    /*
    Implement the Recipes class, which handle food recipes (name, description). The class should have an add (add a new recipe)
    */

    ArrayList<RecipeBean> recipes = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Function to add recipe to recipes ArrayList
     *
     * @param recipeName - Recipe Name
     * @param recipeDescription - Recipe Description
     */
    public void addRecipe(final String recipeName, final String recipeDescription) {
    
        System.out.println("Adding recipe : " + recipeName);

        RecipeBean recipeBean = new RecipeBean();

        recipeBean.setRecipeName(recipeName); // Set recipeName to JavaBean
        recipeBean.setRecipeDescription(recipeDescription); // Set recipeDescription to JavaBean

        // Check if ArrayList is null
        if (recipes != null) {
            recipes.add(recipeBean); // Add java bean to ArrayList
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to delete recipe to recipes ArrayList
     *
     * @param recipeName - Recipe Name
     */
    public void deleteRecipe(final String recipeName) {

        System.out.println("Deleting recipe : " + recipeName);

        // Check if ArrayList is null
        if (recipes != null) {

            // Loop through ArrayList and remove current object if name matches passed parameter
            recipes.removeIf(recipe -> recipe.getRecipeName().equalsIgnoreCase(recipeName));
        }
    }
}
```